# Calling an enum inside a function in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm absolutely at a loss on this one. What is my instructor looking for? Any suggestions?

Started something like this, but I'm just off..

```
enum Color: String {

case blue = "orange"
case red = "green"
case yellow = "purple"

}


func complement(_ color) -> String {
    case
}
```

Question: 
Create a type, `Color` with the three primary colors and the three secondary colors. Then create a function `complement` which will return the complementary color for a provided color.

```
Red's complement is green
Blue's complement is orange
Yellow's complement is purple

complement(.red) -> .green
complement(.orange) -> .blue
```

updated:

```
enum Color: String {
    case red = "red"
    case green = "green"
    case blue = "blue"

    case yellow = "yellow"
    case orange = "orange"
    case purple = "purple"
}

func compliment(_ color: Color) -> Color {
    switch color {
    case .red: return .green
    case .green: return .red
    case .blue: return .orange
    break
    }
}

let red = Color.red
let compliment = compliment(red)
print(compliment)

let green = Color.green
let compliment = compliment(green)
print(compliment)

let blue = Color.blue
let compliment = compliment(blue)
print(compliment)
```

> error: variable used within its own initial value

```
let compliment = compliment(red)
```

It's doing this for every instance

Comment: you could make it work for any color if you take it a little further and [mathematically calculate the complementary color](http://serennu.com/colour/rgbtohsl.php)

Comment: @ForestKunecke That's way overcomplicating this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's the first part are you stuck at?

Comment: Started to do this:
    
enum Color: String {
    
case blue = "orange"
case red = "green"
case yellow = "purple"

}


func complement(_ color) -> String {
    case
}

Comment: the function `complement` needs a type for the parameter `color`.  Check out [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_functions.htm) for a quick primer on functions.

Comment: That's a good start. You should make one enumeration case for every colour, and not have strings and case names mismatched, as they currently are.

Comment: Do you know what a `switch` is?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, I'll give you enough of a pointer to get you started, but won't do it for you.

```
enum Color: String {
    case red = "red"
    case green = "green"
    case blue = "blue"

    case yellow = "yellow"
    case orange = "orange"
    case purple = "purple"
}

func complement(_ color: Color) -> Color {
    switch color {
    case .red: return .green
    case .green: return .red
    case .blue: return .orange
    // etc.
    }
}

let red = Color.red
let compliment = complement(red)
print(compliment)
```

And without getting too deep into color theory, the complement of red isn't blue - it's cyan. For green it's magenta. And blue's complement is yellow.

Comment: Don't submit complete solutions to homework questions. Guide the OP along, instead.

Comment: getting this as an error: variable used within its own initial value
let compliment = compliment(red)

Comment: Check your spelling. I had a mispell in my code which made everything ok. Name your variable something else

Comment: Change the variable names to `redCompliment`, `blueCompliment`, etc. You kept redefining the `compliment` variable

Comment: ohh makes sense. i'm trying to add a break but it's still saying that the switch isn't exhaustive. I don't have a default case. how do i use break?

Comment: That's for your homework. Can you define the complimentary for all 6 colors?

Answer (score 0):

This is more generic. You don't have to create a type with explicit `String`.

```
enum Color {
    case red
    case green
    case blue

    case orange
    case yellow
    case violet
}

func complement(_ color: Color) -> Color {
    switch color {

    case .red: return .green
    case .green: return .red

    case .blue: return .orange
    case .orange: return .blue

    case .yellow: return .violet
    case .violet: return .yellow

    }
}

let red = Color.red
let redComplement = complement(red)
print("Complement of \(red) is \(redComplement)")

let green = Color.green
let greenComplement = complement(green)
print("Complement of \(green) is \(greenComplement)")
```

Comment: In this switch, why don't you need to input a default? What's the difference?

Comment: @ThotOrijn Because all possible cases are explicitly exhausted. There's no unaccounted case that would warrant having a `default`

Comment: **Switch** must be exhaustive. It means, you should cover all of the possible values. Now, you are switching on `Color` and the `Color` has the 6 possible values and you have covered 6 cases. So you don't have other to consider. That's why it's not complaining about _exhaustiveness_

Comment: @ThotOrijn And let's try out _commenting one of the switch cases, you will have that error saying:_ ***consider adding a default clause***. Then you will be able to add the `default` case.